# HTML 5 Canvas : Uploaded image colour picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm creating an application using html canvas and javascript. You upload and image and colour pick from it however I'm having an issue where I can only colour pick colours from a small section of the uploaded image. I've tried a few things to fix it and I'm a bit stumped. Anyone have any ideas?
I used this to help me: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/03/how-to-create-a-color-picker-with-html5-canvas/

```
<canvas width="600" height="300" id="canvas_picker"></canvas>
<div id="hex">HEX: <input type="text"></input></div>
<div id="rgb">RGB: <input type="text"></input></div>
```

```js
var $files = document.getElementById('file_upload').files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    // canvas
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas_picker');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var $img = $('<img>', { src: e.target.result });

    // Draws Image
    $img.load(function() {
        context.drawImage(this,10, 10);
        $("#loader").hide();
    }); 
}

$('#canvas_picker').click(function(event){
    // getting user coordinates
    var x = event.pageX;
    var y = event.pageY;

    // getting image data and RGB values
    var img_data = canvas.getImageData(x,y , 1, 1).data;
    var R = img_data[0];
    var G = img_data[1];
    var B = img_data[2]; 
    var rgb = R + ',' + G + ',' + B;
    // convert RGB to HEX
    var hex = rgbToHex(R,G,B);
    // making the color the value of the input
    console.log(R);
    console.log(B);
    console.log(G);

    $('#rgb input').val(rgb);
    console.log(rgb);
    $('#hex input').val('#' + hex);
});

function rgbToHex(R, G, B) {
    return toHex(R) + toHex(G) + toHex(B)
}

function toHex(n) {
    n = parseInt(n, 10);
    if (isNaN(n)) 
        return "00";

    n = Math.max(0, Math.min(n, 255));
    return "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt((n - n % 16) / 16)  + "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(n % 16);
}
reader.readAsDataURL($files);
```

when I click on a pixel outside the small area, it comes back as 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/qomaxa/1/edit?html,css,js,output)***

Fixed some issues like `getImageData` trying to read `canvas` instead of it's `context`,  and the image being drawn at XY 10,10 instead of 0,0.
Additionally you might want to **adjust the Canvas size** to the uploaded image W/H.

In order to prevent coordinates miscalculations (cause you're getting the click coordinate respective to the page edges) and to get the **exact position of the mouse inside the canvas**, you might want to **subtract** the canvas offset left / top from the resulting coordinate `x`, `y`

```js
var $picked = $("#picked"); // Just to preview picked colors
var canvas = $('#canvas_picker')[0];
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


$("#file_upload").change(function (e) {
  var F = this.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
  reader.readAsDataURL(F);  
});

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(){
    canvas.width  = this.width;    // If needed? adjust canvas size
    canvas.height = this.height;   // respective to image size
    context.drawImage(this, 0, 0); // Draw image at 0, 0, not at 10, 10
  };
  img.src = e.target.result;
}

$('#canvas_picker').click(function(event){
  var x = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left; // Fixed coordinates
  var y = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top; // respective to canvas offs.
  var img_data = context.getImageData(x,y , 1, 1).data;
  var R = img_data[0];
  var G = img_data[1];
  var B = img_data[2]; 
  var rgb = R + ',' + G + ',' + B ;
  var hex = rgbToHex(R,G,B);
  $('#rgb input').val( rgb );
  $('#hex input').val('#' + hex);
  $picked.append("<span style='background:#"+hex+"'>#"+hex+"</span>");
});

function rgbToHex(R, G, B) {
  return toHex(R) + toHex(G) + toHex(B);
}

function toHex(n) {
  n = parseInt(n, 10);
  if (isNaN(n))  return "00";
  n = Math.max(0, Math.min(n, 255));
  return "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt((n - n % 16) / 16)  + "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(n % 16);
}
```

```css
*{margin:0;}
canvas{background:#ddd;}
#picked span{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  margin:3px;
  text-align:center;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
  font:8px/50px Arial;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="600" height="300" id="canvas_picker"></canvas><br>
<input type="file" id="file_upload"><br>
<div id="hex">HEX: <input type="text"></div>
<div id="rgb">RGB: <input type="text"></div>

<div id="picked"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I try your code, it works perfectly well, except the mouse is not well aligned with the picker. This is because you render the image at (10,10) coordinate but you get at mouse pos (x,y).

```
// I replaced the following code
var $img = $('<img>', { src: e.target.result });
$img.load(function() {
    context.drawImage(this,10, 10);
    $("#loader").hide();
}); 
// By this one
var img = new Image();
$img.load(function() {
    context.drawImage(this,10, 10);
    $("#loader").hide();
}); 
img.src = e.target.result;
```

To avoid creating a HTML element that is not really used.
I also put the setting of the click event of the canvas_picker in the DOM Ready, but I think this is not the problem. I also fixed the canvas problem in the click function.

```
// getting image data and RGB values
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas_picker');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img_data = context.getImageData(x,y , 1, 1).data;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
const xOffset = 0, yOffset = 0, width = canvas.width, height = canvas.height;

var inputValues = {image:"https://pinnacle.works/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/dummy-image-300x298.jpg",imageColor:"black"}


DrawBadge('https://pinnacle.works/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/dummy-image-300x298.jpg', '#000');

function DrawBadge(image ,imageColor) {
    
  ctx.lineWidth = 0;

  //Draw Image
  const firstImage = new Image();
  const insideWidth = 148, insideHeight = 148;
  firstImage.src = image;
  // Because of the CORS issue just show image as it is
 
    firstImage.onload = () => {
      //Make new canvas for image
      const imageCtx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
      const insideImage = new Image();
      imageCtx.canvas.width = insideWidth;
      imageCtx.canvas.height = insideHeight;
      imageCtx.save();
      imageCtx.fillStyle = imageColor;
      imageCtx.fillRect(0, 0, insideWidth, insideHeight);
      //Here magic happend 
      imageCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
      imageCtx.drawImage(firstImage,0,0,insideWidth,insideHeight);
      //Then export our canvas to png image
      insideImage.src = imageCtx.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      insideImage.onload = () => {
          ctx.drawImage(insideImage,0,0,insideWidth,insideHeight);
      }
    }
  
}

function download_image(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = "my-image.png";
  link.href = image;
  link.click();
}

      jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        Raphael.colorwheel($("#show_off")[0],300 , 180).color("#FF6600").onchange(function(c){
            DrawBadge('https://pinnacle.works/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/dummy-image-300x298.jpg', c.hex);
       

        });
        
        
      });
```

```html
// How to change canvas image color on click on color picker in jquery?


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.2/raphael-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="https:/raw.githubusercontent.com/jweir/colorwheel/master/colorwheel.js"></script>
 
 
 
  <div class="row">

                                                        <div class="col-md-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-12">
                                                             <canvas width="148" height="148"  id="canvas"></canvas>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="col-md-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-12 mt-5">
                                                                <div id="show_off" class="colorpicker_buton">

                                                                </div>
                                                        </div>
                            <div class="mt_canvasimag_download_png mt-5">
                                                     <button class="canvasimag_download_png" onclick="download_image()">Download PNG</button>
                                                  </div>
                                              </div>
```